# Limit the number of private key uses for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 with SHA-256 signature?

Tags: rsa, signature, key-reuse, pkcs11

Assuming all messages and their signatures are available to the attacker, is it secure to use the same RSA private key to sign many messages (roughly $10^{6}$) via PKCS#11 `CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS` using a reasonably long (i.e. 2048 bit) key?

For reference, `CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS` is described as follows:

> The PKCS #1 v1.5 RSA signature with SHA-256 mechanism, denoted `CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS`, performs single- and multiple-part digital signatures and verification operations without message recovery.  The operations performed are as described initially in PKCS #1 v1.5 with the object identifier `sha256WithRSAEncryption`, and as in the scheme `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` in the current version of PKCS #1, where the underlying hash function is SHA-256.